# How to deploy my vitepress to azure static web app with base url?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-static-web-app, vitepress

Now I can deploy the website to http:xxxxxx/index.html, but what I want to do now is to deploy it to http:xxxxx/web/myapp/index.html, so I set the `base` options in the Vitepress to make it serve at `/web/myapp`, it works in my local environment ( `npm run docs:serve` will show `localhost:5173/web/myapp/index.html`, but when I deploy the app to azure static web app, the main file will be unable to find any css / js resource, and when you try to go to http:xxxxx/web/myapp/index.html, it will show 404 in return

Here's related setting

Azure

```json
app_location: "docs/.vitepress/dist"
skip_app_build: true
```

Vitepress

```json
base: '/web/myapp'
```

Now my guess is when you build the application, the location is still at `/dist`, in the static web app, it will try to find the resource at `web/myapp/assets/index.css` so it won't be able to find related file since the file exist in `/assets/index.css`.

How Azure static web app solve this kind of problems ?

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem. Here is how I solved it:

```js
// .vitepress/config.js

const { BASE: base = '/' } = process.env
export default { base, outDir: `../dist/docs${base}` }
```

```
// package.json

"docs:dev": "vitepress dev docs",
"docs:build": "vitepress build docs",
"docs:serve": "vitepress serve docs",
"build": "pnpm docs:build && BASE='/foo/' pnpm docs:build"
```

This issue from GitHub maybe helpful: [How can I set the base url for 2 different domains](https://github.com/vuejs/vitepress/issues/750)